# Accept Old Password To Edit Settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model with a settings page at /users/1/edit

Currently you can change the email and change your password (w/ confirmation).

I would like to have a field called "current_password" where the user has to type their current password before they can change any information.

Here is my form now:
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

```
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>


<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Obviously if I just add the field in, it gives me an error because my user model doesn't have a "current_password" attribute.

How can I do this? Is there a better way, possibly?

Comment: what does the validation look like (in your model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add it to the model and database or this to your model:

```
add attr_reader :current_password
```

Then you can do a validation of that in your model.